# add specific word in all links or URL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have live website in laravel and 50+ links or URL

Current Url of Home Page: `mysite.com/index.php/home` or `mysite.com/index.php`

I want add products in all URL

**For exampl**e: `mysite.com/index.php/products/home`

i can do manually add product in all links but it take so much time. please provide alternative way

Comment: Pretty much the only (or major at least) point of using `route('name')` for your routes is that you can safely change the route in your routes file whenever you want to whatever you want (with same number of arguments) and all the links will magically still work (since they're dynamically generated with `route(...)`. I don't see the issue.

Comment: Okay, you actually never mentioned you use `route(...)` or `action(...)`. How do you actually insert the links in your HTML?

Comment: in html my website link look like this {{url("profiles")}}

Comment: @devk please give me some examples of code.. what should i change in route file..

Comment: I can't help you any further without knowing how you have your links and routes set up. Here's an example from my project `<a href="{{ route('findBySlug', $page->slug) }}")>goto</a>`.  I doubt this is of any help to your specific project so please expand more on how you set up your rotes and links if you want help.

Comment: Where does the `{{ url('profiles') }}` point to? I assume `mysite.com/profiles`? Judging by your original post that's not a viable route anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Namespace in your Laravel route and then give route prefixes in your file

documentation on laravel for the same can be seen here
[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups)